# Can you return certain value upon matching an expression in java

Tags: java, regex

Can you return a value from regex upon match ? Say I had regex (^(a|an)$) It will be true when it gets "a" or "an" as input. Can I modify it to return value 1 if it matches in java? 0 should be returned if it does not match. I will want to replace the value returned in future to 2 instead of 1.

Comment: Wrap it in your own method? As long as `false` will be zero or other numeric value.

Comment: What should be returned if it wont match?

Comment: 0 should be returned if it wont match

Comment: `return (<regex boolean result> ? 1:0);`

Comment: Why would you return 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;  

public static int matches(String str, String regex) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
    return matcher.matches() ? 1 : 0;
};
```

Comment: Thanks.I guess you have to handle returning specific value in code.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `String.matches()` and ternary operator to convert the result to 0/1:

```
inputString.matches(pattern) ? 1 : 0;
```